# "Cannot open database - login failed" . Works in Management Studio, not code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, umbraco, ssms

Oh yes, the famous error:

> Cannot open database "MYDBNAME" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'USERNAME'.

**Let me explain my situation:**

I have a database server, which has a SA account and my user account. The user has the correct mappings to my database (dbowner).

I can open the database with this user, using SQL Management Studio 2008 R2, both on the SQL server itself (using localhost), and on my frontend server.

However, when I run my application, I get the login failed error.

Strange thing is I have a test application and a production application on our frontend server. The test application has test databases on the same database server, and there are no login problems here. The only difference between the two, are the prefix which differs from "TEST" to "PROD". The test application works, the production however, doesn't. The user mappings and seem it should work on both.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Our connectionstring:

```
<add key="umbracoDbDSN" value="Server=Websqlsrv01;Database=PROD_Databasename;User ID=umbraco_user;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False" />
```

Comment: Can you show us the connection string you use in your code?

Comment: Of course. Just added the connectionstring :-)

Comment: What happens if you remove the "TrustedConnection=False" and just leave the other 4 properties?

Comment: Nothing at all - same error unfortunately.

Comment: Compare the ff between your two environments: select * from sys.database_permissions where grantee_principal_id = user_id('umbraco_user')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql server has a dichotomy  login/user

they are 2 different entity:

http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_logins_and_users.html

maybe your sql login is not associated with an user for database PROD_Databasename but only for TEST_Databasename

another cause could be the user default database or eventually different database schemas

you can easily check if one of those is the problem simply creating a new user for PROD_Databasename and using it in connectionstring.

another way is to execute

```
exec sp_helpuser
```

in both databases (PROD and TEST) and see if the username "umbraco_user" is listed.

Anyway it is not a good practice to use same login for 2 different users:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/is-there-any-benefit-to-having-one-sql-server-login-for-multiple-users

Comment: The default database is master. I've tried several different databases - no help :-(

Comment: @Mcoroklo i added some tests in my answer. Try to do them.

Comment: It turned out it was some kind of cache, as it suddenly worked when I tried this morning. I don't understand by, as I made sure my cache was cleared... 

Anyway, your bet would definetely be the best guess for most cases. Therefore I select your answer as "the answer" .

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to use `servername\instancename` in your connection string if you've setup something other than a *default* instance. Use [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/eb58a7fe-4647-4eea-91e3-6ee369362d64/) link to find your instance name. Give that a try!

Answer (score 0):

right click on you application and run as admin. This should work!